# Within transaction: Use inserted id for reference to next insertion

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I want to create a wallet for a user, when the user itself is being created. Ideally i want this to happen within a transaction, as one may not exist without the other.

I want something like this, in Ecto paradigm.

```
BEGIN;
  INSERT INTO albums [...];
  INSERT INTO album_images (lastval(), image_id) [...];
COMMIT;
```

Taken from https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/2154.

How would achieve such?

Comment: So what's the question exactly? How to use transactions with Ecto?

Comment: Just put the two inserts inside a `Repo.transaction`. You can use the return value of the first insert in the second insert.

Comment: Use insert returning. insert into tablea returning id... put that id into the next insert and voila you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `Multi` and at the end you would put all the things processed in the Multi to `Repo.transaction()`.

[Ecto.Multi](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html) will help you to organize this flow, because Multi.run accepts Multi structure that contains result of previous computation - that's why you can safely use it, because if first operation fails, the second one will be rejected by the transaction as well.

The best way to write it is to put the business operations to separate functions, where the second one accept Multi with the name of the result of previous operation.

```
Multi.new
|> Multi.insert(:albums, insert_albums(arguments))
|> Multi.run(:album_images, AlbumImage, :insert, [])
|> Repo.transaction()
```

where `AlbumImage.insert` might look like:

```
defmodule AlbumImage do
  def insert(%{albums: albums}) do
    # code
  end
end
```